# AWS CLI Query for pulling image from ecs describe-task-definition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, docker, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

So I'm trying to pull just the image from a task-definition. I'm running:

`aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition nameoftaskdefinition --output text`

And I'm trying add in the --query option so that result will look like

`VAR = $(aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition nameoftaskdefinition --output text)`

where `echo $VAR` would return `image`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the output from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-task-definition.html), you'll want something like this (untested)

```sh
aws ecs describe-task-definition \
    --task-definition nameoftaskdefinition \
    --query 'taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[].image' \
    --output text
```

Note that depending on your task, you may have multiple `containerDefinitions`, so the output from that command (`$VAR` in your example) could be a space separated string

Comment: I can't tell you how much time I wasted - thank you! My use case almost always only has one container definition but I'll keep it mind so this works out great